# Liferay 6.2 cannot fetch compass after portlet deployment

Tags: jboss, sass, liferay, liferay-6, compass

After deploying contacts-portlet in jboss (changes in main.js), css of contacts-portlet is not loaded because of an error regarding compass.
The same portlet exists also on a staging environment with jboss also running as application server. I copied the exact same contacts-portlet.war from staging to production, after deleting the existing on production. After the new deployment, the compass not found error is still displayed on firebug console.
Has anybody met something similar? 
[image: firebug console error]
The [6.1 compass issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446438/failed-to-load-compass-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not) is not the case in Liferay 6.2.

Any help would be appreciated.